# Catalyst and Inhibitors home experiments

Tags: home-experiment

My teacher assigned me a science experience involving catalysts and inhibitors at home.

I think I understand the principle of it, but I fail to find possible experiments that I can do at home with a thermostat and some home substances.

The experience:

3 reactions...
1 with the catalyst,
1 with the inhibitor,
1 without anything.

I will compare them by measuring the reaction speed with a factor (preferably the heat variation).

EDIT: I can also measure the volume of the product.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look up the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide, $\ce{H2O2}$. The 3% solution sold as antiseptic should be safe to use at home, as would be some readily available catalysts and inhibitors.

[Horseradish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseradish_peroxidase) might be used for a catalyst... but don't eat it in the lab.

To measure speed of reaction, measure gas evolution with an inverted, liquid-filled graduated cylinder or small measuring cup over time.

You can have fun [burning things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlSeHSDc-Do) (**carefully**) in the evolved $\ce{O2}$, too.

Comment: Thank you, I am not really good in chemistry, but what I understand is that I need mix the solution with some horseradish powder so that the decomposition of H2O2 happens faster? In this experience, what will the inhibitor be? I don't think I will burn something in the O2; I will breath it :-)

Comment: Actually, *fresh* horseradish probably has more peroxidase than powdered. But there are many other catalysts you can use. Use the 'net, young master... there is a plethora of info on peroxide catalysts and inhibitors.